# ¿Por qué si no utilizo el useState de "setCount" solo se actualiza si meto algo en el onChange?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

¿Por qué tengo que poner un `setCount(count+1);}}/>` en la línea 15 para que funcione el *toDo*?
Porque si quito ese `useState` solo se me actualiza si meto algo en el `onChange` de la línea 14. Me gustaría comprenderlo.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

var arr = new Array()
function App() {
  const [texto, setTexto] = useState("")
  const [lista, setLista] = useState([])
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);



  return (
    <>
    <input type="text" name="" id="textoinput" onChange={(e)=>{setTexto(e.target.value)}}/>
    <input type="button" value="Ok" onClick={(e)=>{arr.push(texto);setLista(arr);setCount(count+1);}}/>
    <br/><br/>

    {lista.length>0?lista.map((e,i)=>{return <div key={i+"_div"}> {e} <input type="button" value="delete" onClick={(e)=>{}}  /> 
     </div>
    }):""}
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Si el título difiere de lo que fue la intención original, modifícalo. Por favor, lee [ask]: tal como estaba redactada la pregunta anteriormente, hubiera sido de utilidad solo para ti. Recuerda que la pregunta y sus respuestas deben ser útiles también para los demás miembros de la comunidad que tengan una pregunta o un problema similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No aparece nada, porque de la forma que lo haces, si no pones el setcount no renderiza el componente y por tanto no muestra los elementos que si hay añadidos en la variable lista. Yo sacaría y modificaría la lógica de añadir un elemento a una función.

```
function add(){
  const newList = [...lista]
  newList.push(texto)
  setLista(newList)
  setTexto("");
}
```

y el input quedaría así

```
<input type="button" value="Ok" onClick={add}/>
```

también me ahorraría usar la variable count, si quieres mostrar el total, solo tienes que poner `lista.length`

Comment: Gracias! me ha sido útil tu respuesta!